# Angular.js show loading animation until DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a Phonegap application with Angular.js. From the index page you can click on the "Show user list" button which redirects you to a page which loads a template in `ng-view`. The template contains the list of users, which are loaded from `$rootScope.users` and rendered with `ng-repeat`. The problem is that there are many users (about 120 for now) so the page rendering is slow, especially in Phonegap. So, when I click on the "Show user list" button, the URL in the address bar changes immediately, but the content in `ng-view` changes only after a few seconds. Because of that, I want to display a loading animation until the view is rendered, so the user knows that the page is loading.

I created a loading animation - a div with `ng-show="loading.visible"`. On the button, I set `ng-click="loading.visible=true"` and in the controller of the "users" page i wrote:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
            $scope.loading.visible = false;
        })
```

It works great the first time the button is pressed. The animation shows immediately and disappears when the user list shows. But when I go back to the index page, and press the "Show user list" button again, the loading animation doesn't show up until the user list is rendered, then it shows up for about 100ms and disappears.

I'm new to Angular so I'm not really sure how it works, can someone tell me what's wrong and is there a better solution to handle this problem? Thanks

Comment: [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak). Use Custom CSS to load a spinner/splash screen. This is not working most likely because the JS hasn't loaded completely on the page by the time the DOM is delivered to the user.

Comment: what about ngCloak? I already have that directive in <body>

Answer (score 4):

try using below in your page controller

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () 
{
     $scope.loading.visible = false;
});
```

instead of

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){});
```

Also look for ng-cloak in angular documentation.

Hope this helps.

Thanks